# DataTable Load method freezes or not by sql query (with same data)

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, datatable

The code was working correctly about 1 hour ago (and still works correctly in test database).

```
public static int ExecuteNonQuery(String pCommand, CommandType pCommandType, ref OracleParameter[] pParameters)
{
    int retVal = 0;

    using (OracleConnection connection = ConnectToDB())
    {
        using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandType = pCommandType;
            command.CommandText = pCommand.ToString();

            if (pParameters != null)
            {
                command.Parameters.AddRange(pParameters);
            }

            retVal = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            DataTable dt = null;

            command.Parameters.Cast<OracleParameter>()
                .Where(
                    p =>
                        p.Value != DBNull.Value && 
                        p.Direction == ParameterDirection.Output &&
                        p.OracleType == OracleType.Cursor)
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(p =>
                {
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    dt.Load((p.Value as OracleDataReader));
                    p.Value = dt;
                });
        }
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

but now it doesn't work correctly, at **dt.Load** line freezes. There is no known changes in query and in code. Same sql query, same source code but behaving is different.

SQL query result contains 658 rows. We don't think that is about data count but tried increase data count from 1 step by step with **ROWNUM < X** condition and it started working correctly. At the end **ROWNUM < 10000** is a temporary solution for us but we still don't understand why it freezes at dt.Load line.

Comment: So, what changed during the last hour?

Comment: Does it ever finish?  I've seen similar code freeze on a SQL Server.  It just takes a long time to do a query.  So I usually put code in a backgroundworker to prevent the freezing.  Code still take long time to complete.  The database may of gotten fragmented which could increase time or the database is now a lot larger.

Comment: Are you using ODP.NET? T?Here shouldn't be need for you do do so much coding. odp.net takes car of getting your cursor parameter and filling reader. `reader = cmd.Execute.Reader; Dt.Load(reader)`. And if you have >1 cursors, it will create reader results. 1 cursor = 1 result.Call `reader.NextResult()`

Comment: @Littlefoot we don't know what changed and the problem is in only one project, we have similar projects and they don't have problem.

Comment: @jdweng it may finish but I think because of web service time out it crashes.

Comment: The look at the Oracle log files.  If the database crashes then a timeout would occur in the c# application and you would get an exception indicating the timeout.

Comment: @jdweng Database doesn't crash, we run same query on Toad and it works in acceptable time.